# how to differentiate ajax call and browser request in php (or codeigniter)?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

is there a way to differentiate ajax call and normal browser request in php (or codeigniter to be specific)?

this is my jquery ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').load('http://localhost/index.php/customer/'); 
});
```

this is the index method of customer controller in codeigniter:

```
public function index() {
    //if (call == 'ajax request') 
    //  do this if it's an ajax request;
    //else
    //  do that if user directly type the link in the address bar;
    $this->load->view('customer/listview');
}
```

any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CodeIgniter way..

```
$this->input->is_ajax_request()
```

Comment: wow, it works. guess i didn't read the input class thoroughly. thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

```
function getIsAjaxRequest()
{
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']==='XMLHttpRequest';
}
```

Define this function somewhere then of course use it like this:

```
if (getIsAjaxRequest())
// do this
else
// do that
```

But there might be such thing already in CodeIgniter implemented, just global search for HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH

Comment: it's $this->input->is_ajax_request() in codeigniter. but it's +1 experience to see how the method actually works. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {}
```

Should do what you need. Though it can obviously be faked like any other HTTP Header, so don't rely on it for anything major.

Answer (score 0):

This is Codeigniter's implementation of this functionality.

```
if($this->input->isAjax()) {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on server variables which might get changed eg. if the server is behind a reverse proxy I do all my AJAX calls through a single javascript function in which I add a POST variable: isajax. Then I check for it using something like $this->UI->IsAJAX() which looks for a varible that was initialized while setting up the controller.

```
$this->_isAJAX = (empty($_POST['isajax']) ? true : false.
```

Comment: My answer is useful if you are not using a framework, I wouldn't recommend writing your own functions for making AJAX calls and setting POST variables(other than application logic of course).